# "power button action" Missing in Fedora 23

Tags: fedora, gnome-shell

I Recently upgraded to Fedora 23.  I noticed "power button action" is missing from gnome-tweak-tool. It is also not available in dconf-editor. 
Even in terminal It is not available.

```
[Abhinav@localhost ~] $ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power 'shutdown'
No such key 'button-power'
[Abhinav@localhost ~] $
```

I used to set it to shutdown so that I just need to press power button and laptop would shut itself down. But now it instead go to sleep.
How do I get that setting back in F23.

Comment: This also happens to me. I read `man logind.conf` and then uncommented the line `HandlePowerKey=poweroff` in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`, but it still keeps suspending when pressing the power button rather than powering off.

Comment: Yes I already tried that. Looks like they have removed this functionality. Too bad.  I read a G+ post that they plan to include this in `power` section in gnome-settings. I wonder what made them think removing essentials from tweak-tool is a good approch, when they don't have their own ready for use.

Comment: This feature was removed from `gnome-settings-daemon` and is not going to be restored in the foreseeable future. If you want to re-enable it you'll have to patch the source code; [follow my guide here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/242452)

Comment: Nice guide @don_crissti . l have `power-button-action`in dconf-editor but it only have options for `nothing`, `suspend` and `hibernate` . not option for `shutdown` .  I crashed the system once trying to patch it. I will try again following your

Comment: Just curious, is there an another way to configure this, instead of patching the software itself.  Currently I installed `acpi` and  changed `/etc/acpi/events/powerconf` file and changed action to `/sbin/poweroff`. This is working for me so far but i do like your way to add a configuration in GUI tool. Just scared to patch a mainstream software.

Comment: As I said in my post there, you cannot set the power button to shutdown via gnome GUI unless you patch the source code. My patch also provides the `shutdown` option in `dconf` which is otherwise missing from a standard system. It's easy to use a custom patched version of a package if you're familiar with your system (and revert to stock package if something goes wrong). I cannot guide your through that though... But you can always try my patch in a VM.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
gsettings range org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power power-button-action
```

Comment: Can you expand your answer to explain how this command works?

Answer (score 0):

The following answer answers it:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/242129/gnome-3-how-to-set-power-button-to-shutdown-instead-of-suspend

In a nutshell, run `dconf-editor` and browse to *org > gnome > settings-daemon > plugins > power > power-button-action*.